# Python - How can i show different things depending on the user type

Tags: python

Depending if the login is an "user" or a admin"
How can i make this so it returns a value that i can then use to print different things?
For example if i input a type of login {user} then it should take the user to a menu showing "(welcome user!)", but if the input is an {admin} then it should take the admin to a menu showing "(welcome admin!)

```
class Login():

    def grantAccess():
              <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< define your function here!
    #please print a statements that says ("this is the admins menu!") for the admins and
    #the users print a statements that says ("this is the users menu!")

#checks on mysql is the user exists
    def userExists(id):
        con = connect()
        sqlSelect = f"""SELECT user FROM table WHERE id= "{id}" """
        cursor = con.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sqlSelect)
        cursor.fetchall()
        if cursor.rowcount == 1 :
            #user exists
            return True
        else:
            #does not exist
            return False
    #for the user login
    #check if user and password are correct
    def correctUsLogin(user, password):
        con = connect()
        sqlSelect = f"""SELECT user, password FROM users WHERE user= "{user}" AND BINARY password= "{password}" """
        cursor = con.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sqlSelect)
        cursor.fetchall()
        if cursor.rowcount == 1 :
            #user and password correct
            return True
        else:
            #user or password incorrect
            return False
    #for the admin login
    def corrrectAdLogin(user, password):
        con = connect()
        sqlSelect = f"""SELECT user, password FROM admins WHERE user = "{user}" AND BINARY password = "{password}" """
        cursor = con.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sqlSelect)
        cursor.fetchall()
        if cursor.rowcount == 1 :
            #user and password correct
            return True
        else:
            #user or password incorrect
            return False    

    #login
    def userLogin(user, password):
        #serch in db table "users"<<<
        if Login.correctUsLogin(user, password) == True:
        #here it should grant the access to the users menu                      <<<<<<<<<
        Login.grantAccess()
        else:
            print("ERROR, user or password incorrect")
            input("Press a key to continue...")
            os.system("cls")
            Login.start()

    def adminLogin(user, password):
        #serch in db table "admins"<<<
        if Login.corrrectAdLogin(user, password) == True:
        #here it should grant the access to the administrators menu              <<<<<<<<<
            Login.grantAccess()
        else:
            print("ERROR, user or password incorrect")
            input("Press a key to continue......")
            os.system("cls")
            Login.start()

    #depending on the user inputs do...
    def access(opcion):
        if opcion == "1": #for normal user
            print("---Iniciar sesion---")
            id = input("Ingrese el id: ")
            password = input("Ingrese la password: ")
            Login.userLogin(id, password)

        elif opcion == "3": #for admin
            print("---Iniciar sesion---")
            id = input("Ingrese el id: ")
            password = input("Ingrese la password: ")
            Login.adminLogin(id, password)
    #code starts
    def start():
        print('---Museo "Fósiles" de Magallanes---')
        opcion = input("login user(1) / register(2) / login admin(3): ")
        if opcion != "1" and opcion != "2" and opcion != "3":
            print("ERROR, input a correct option")
            input("Press a key to continue......")
            os.system("cls")
            Login.start()
        else:
            Login.access(opcion)    



sorry for my shitty code
and there are things that i might have not translated right, english is not my native language
thanks!
```

Comment: Just add a parameter to the grant access method and tell the method who is logging in and what menu they are seeing... Then the grant acess can just have a general message that works for all inputs

Comment: @Alexander, why not post your suggestion as an answer?

I see an indentation issue in userLogin() and I wonder why this whole thing is happening inside a class (Login).  While the Login object ever be instantiated?

Comment: @twohot this isn't exactly a very high quality question so, I prefer to just leave suggestions in the comments when I come across those.